# Mysql query order starts with then contains

Tags: mysql

How to select and ordered all results that start with `LIKE 'a%` and then contains `LIKE '%a%'` with a limit of e.g. 3.

For example the following dataset: b, aab, baa, cad, ccc, bb, ac.
The desired result is to get aab, ac, baa.
(If the limit is 2, no items for contains should be returned.)

Comment: why is the result of baa okay but cad is not?

Comment: SELECT * from table WHERE column like any ('{"%a%", "a%"}');

Comment: @ChrisBanks The result baa is ok, caa is also relevant but due the limit of 3 this should not be in the desired result because of the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case this works:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM table1
WHERE (Column1 LIKE 'a%' OR Column1 LIKE '%a%')
ORDER BY Column1
LIMIT 3
```

The case below should work, replace `table1` and `Column1` for the real names, and try `Limit 2` and `Limit 3`.
This case is useful when `a` can be `yourcustomstring` too:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM (
    SELECT Column1 
    FROM table1
    WHERE Column1 LIKE 'a%'
    ORDER BY Column1
) T1
UNION 
SELECT Column1 FROM 
(
    SELECT Column1 
    FROM table1
    WHERE Column1 LIKE '%a%'
    ORDER BY Column1
) T2
LIMIT 3
```

Working example:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT YourTableAsUnion.Column1
        FROM (SELECT 'b' AS Column1
        UNION 
        SELECT 'aab'
        UNION
        SELECT 'baa'
        UNION 
        SELECT 'cad'
        UNION 
        SELECT 'ccc'
        UNION 
        SELECT 'bb'
        UNION
        SELECT 'ac'
        ) YourTableAsUnion
        WHERE YourTableAsUnion.Column1 LIKE 'a%'
        ORDER BY YourTableAsUnion.Column1
    ) T1
    UNION SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT YourTableAsUnion.Column1
        FROM (SELECT 'b' AS Column1
        UNION 
        SELECT 'aab'
        UNION
        SELECT 'baa'
        UNION 
        SELECT 'cad'
        UNION 
        SELECT 'ccc'
        UNION 
        SELECT 'bb'
        UNION
        SELECT 'ac'
        ) YourTableAsUnion
        WHERE YourTableAsUnion.Column1 LIKE '%a%'
        ORDER BY YourTableAsUnion.Column1
    ) T2
    LIMIT 3
```